# Vue how to parse a line break in a textarea string that comes from an Api?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, textarea, line-breaks

I am using Vue 2, I need to show `myText` variable in the textarea with line breaks.  If I use a static variable in the textarea then the line breaks work properly. It shows:

```
line one
line two2
```

but if I get `myText` from an API, it shows the `\n` as text:

```
line one\nline two2
```

This code for clarification

```
 <template>
  <div class="Test">  
    <textarea name="name" v-model="myText" >   </textarea> 
  </div>
</template>
```

the JavaScript

```
 <script>
    export default {
      name: 'Test',
       data: () => ({
          myText: ' line one\nline two2 ' 
       }), 
       created(){
         this.getTextFromApi();
       },
       methods:{
           getTextFromApi(){ 
                ajax()
                 .done(function(Response){ 
                    this.myText = Response.text;   
                 };
           },
      }
    } 
</script>
```

So how do I make the textarea read the `\n` that comes from an Api as a line break, not a text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your API text has double backslashes, like perhaps if a string such as "\n" is being escaped into "\\n" and entered into your API.  If so, this would work:

```js
this.myText = Response.text.replace('\\n','\n');
```

This leaves in the `\n` for line breaks.  The callback seems to need an arrow function too:

```js
.done((Response) => { 
   this.myText = Response.text.replace('\\n','\n');   
})
```